# Unable to make new folder in Apps cache folder

Tags: android, android-file

I have written a caching system. It saves data to the cache folder of the App using platform / Android methods to find the folder. I have an issue that I cannot create a new folder in the Apps cache folder.

This error is reporting in Crashlytics (via non-fatal error reporting) for *some* devices and *not* for the majority.

The method that contains the issue is my `getCacheFolder()` method.

An example folder path that does not work on these devices: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/app.package.name/cache/stream-cache`.

Reported versions affected: `4.4.2`; `5.0.1`; `6.0`, `6.0.1`.

Reported devices affected: `LENOVO YOGA Tablet 2-1050L`, `MOTOROLA MotoE2(4G-LTE)`, `Samsung SM-N910F` (accounts for 98% of faults reported).

My suspicions are that there might be an issue relating to removable sdcards.

```
@NonNull
public File getCacheFolder() {
    // If this is the first run of this library function, we should get our cache folder
    if (mCacheFolder == null || !mCacheFolder.exists()) {
        File dir = null;

        // Prioritise the external sdcard to store cached files
        dir = mContext.get().getExternalCacheDir();
        if(dir == null) {
            // There was no external sdcard - instead use internal storage
            dir = mContext.get().getCacheDir();
        }

        // Still couldn't get a cache location, go to fallback plan and throw exception
        if(dir == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not create a location to cache. " +
                    "This leaves the caching library in a bad state.");
        }

        // Point to our specific caching folder for this system
        mCacheFolder = new File(dir, "stream-cache");
    }

    // If it doesn't exist, we will need to make it
    if (!mCacheFolder.exists()) {
        // If we cannot make the directory, go to fallback plan and throw an exception
        if (!mCacheFolder.mkdirs()) {
            // HERE IS WHERE THE FAULT IS REPORTED
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not create a location to cache. " +
                    "This leaves the caching library in a bad state.: "+mCacheFolder);
        }
    }

    return mCacheFolder;
}
```

### Update 1

I updated the code to write out various information about the state:

```
@NonNull
public File getCacheFolder() {
    if (mCacheFolder == null || !mCacheFolder.exists()) {
        File dir = mContext.get().getExternalCacheDir();
        if(dir == null || !Utils.isExternalStorageWritable()) {
            dir = mContext.get().getCacheDir();
        }

        mCacheFolder = new File(dir, "stream-cache");
    }

    if (!mCacheFolder.exists()) {
        if (!mCacheFolder.mkdirs()) {
            // Problems writing to cache - test writing to file path.
            File filePath = mContext.get().getExternalFilesDir(null);
            File cachePath = new File(filePath, "stream-cache");

            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not create a location to cache. " +
                    "This leaves the caching library in a bad state.: "+mCacheFolder+ ". " +
                    "filePath="+filePath+". " +
                    "cachePath="+cachePath+". " +
                    "cachePath-exists="+cachePath.exists()+". " +
                    "cachePath-mkdirs="+cachePath.mkdirs());
        }
    }

    return mCacheFolder;
}
```

The important results from this:

filePath=null - `Context.getExternalFilesDir(null);` returns a null. Breaking the rest of the tests.

Comment: Pos the Logcat as well.

Comment: There is no crash or log to post. The issue is that `File.mkdirs()` reports false for the mentioned path.

Comment: Did you try Runtime permissions in case you are using Android 6.0+ ?

Comment: I use runtime permissions for saving to the sdcard in other places, but not for cache. I have manifest permissions set up. You surely don't need to ask for permission to write to the cache folder. I think I remember reading that is allowed - but I will investigate.

Comment: Indeed, according to the documentation for `getExternalCacheDir()` : `There is no security enforced with these files. For example, any application holding WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE can write to these files.` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir()

Comment: `// Prioritise the external sdcard to store cached files`. That will not give you a path on a removable sd card. That always gives a path to external memory. See the function name.

Comment: @greenapps: What do you mean? The docs state: `Returns absolute path to application-specific directory on the primary shared/external storage device where the application can place cache files it owns. These files are internal to the application, and not typically visible to the user as media.` - importantly: `external storage device`

Comment: `dir = mContext.get().getCacheDir();` What is type of mContext? Will `getCacheDir()` ever return a `null` ?

Comment: `What do you mean?` I repeat. Those functions will not deliver paths to removable SD cards. You prioritise external memory instead.

Comment: It looks like `getCacheDir()` never returns null - according to docs. That can probably be simplified. `mContext` is a `WeakReference<Context>`.

Comment: And `getExternalCacheDir()` ? A `null` possible?

Comment: Yes, that returns null in the case that: `shared storage is not currently available.`.

Comment: I'm puzzled. `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/app.package.name/cache/stream-cache` is quite a normal path. Have you tried other such directories. Like `getExternalFilesDir()` ? You can just add it to your code and try before you throw.

Comment: I will add that to my code and log the results of it in my non-fatal crash reporting. I noticed I am not checking the writability of external storage before reaching this point. I will add that too `getExternalStorageState()` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState(java.io.File)

Comment: `File.canWrite()` is not reliable  among Android versions or devices. False positive. I ended up trying to create a directory and removing it right away.

Comment: Not using `File.canWrite()` - instead using: `Context.getExternalStorageState()`. That is recommended to ensure the storage isn't read-only or removed, for example: `one of MEDIA_UNKNOWN, MEDIA_REMOVED, MEDIA_UNMOUNTED, MEDIA_CHECKING, MEDIA_NOFS, MEDIA_MOUNTED, MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY, MEDIA_SHARED, MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL, or MEDIA_UNMOUNTABLE.`.

Comment: `to ensure the storage isn't read-only or removed, As told before functions like`getExternalStorageState()` will refer to external storage. And that cannot be removed as it is not removable media. I think the documentation is not updated in quite a time.

Comment: Think i have to correct myself. File.canWrite() is ok for external storage but it failed on some devices for removable media. Now isn't it a pitty that i cannot use getExternalStorageState() for removable media.

Comment: Well, checking the state of the external storage didn't help, and neither did `getExternalFilesDir()`. That returned null. Question updated with current code and results.

Comment: A long time has passed, did you manage to find a solution? I'm having very similar issue, File#mkdirs returns false for (internal) cache dir...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
// Point to our specific caching folder for this system
mCacheFolder = new File(dir, "stream-cache");
```

try using this:

```
// Point to our specific caching folder for this system
mCacheFolder = new File(dir + "/stream-cache");
```

in your first code snippets.

Comment: What would that change?